# Cumulative incidence under competing risks: cannot infer event free survival?

Tags: survival, competing-risks

Suppose one had performed a competing risk analysis and the 10 year cumulative incidence for the event of interest is 60%. Am I correct in thinking that we CANNOT conclude that the event-free survival is 40% since, in competing risk situations, the survival and cumulative incidence are no longer inversely related? If that's right, am I right that we can't really say anything about event-free survival, but rather we should just discuss the cumulative incidence estimates?

Answer (score 3):

That is correct.  For concreteness suppose that you are interested in the risk of cancer and there is a competing risk due to fatal heart attack.  Event-free survival probability at time $t$ is the probability of not having cancer or a fatal heart attack before time $t$.  It can be estimated by computing the Kaplan-Meier estimate for the time until the first of the two events.

On the other hand the cumulative incidence of cancer when fatal heart attack is taken as a competing event is the probability of developing cancer **that preceeds heart attack death**.  Since death will mask some cancer cases, the cumulative incidence curve does not have to reach 1.0 as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

It is often more natural to model multiple event types using multistate transition models.  Therneau, Crowson, and Atkinson have a wonderful article about competing risk and multistate models [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf).  For example you could model the probability of going from a well state to a cancer state or to a fatal heart attack state, the probability of going from a cancer state to a fatal heart attack state, ...  i.e., any transition probabilities you want as a function of time.  From these you can come mean times in various states.

The article referenced above also explains why the commonly used Fine & Gray competing risk cumulative incidence model makes assumptions that are unlikely to hold.

Comment: Thank you! In your first paragraph you seem to suggest event free survival is 1-KM estimate. Isn't it that the event free survival is just the KM estimate (not 1-KM, which gives cumulative incidence if there is just one type of event)?

Comment: Thanks - fixing this now.  Note that thanks is expressed by upvoting anwers, comments, questions.